# setting image on UIIMageView where image name is coming from xml

Tags: xml, uiimageview, uiimage

I am adding an image which is in my Resource folder where image name is coming from a xml file.
Xml parsing is returning the name of image correctly as its showing on console.
Now setting this image using,

```
UIImageView Images=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
Images.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[myEngine.CountryImageArr objectAtIndex:0]];
[self.view addSubview:Images];
```

Here [myEngine.CountryImageArr objectAtIndex:0] is giving correct image name and hardcoding that name show the image on imageview. But at run time as shown in code it can  not show the image on UIImageView.

I also used [UIImage imagewithContentOfFile:] but it also doesnot solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the image name is having correct extensions and all.
Also try

```
UIImageView Images=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage  imageNamed:[myEngine.CountryImageArr objectAtIndex:0]];
[Images setImage:img];
img = nil;
[self.view addSubview:Images];
```

Comment: I checked all these issues and they are all correct. The problem is that if I try to print [myEngine.CountryImageArr objectAtIndex:0] it gives "something.png" but when I make an UIImage from this string like [UIImage  imageNamed:[myEngine.CountryImageArr objectAtIndex:0]] it gives null image.

Comment: NSString *str = [myEngine.CountryImageArr objectAtIndex:0]; UIImageView Images=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage  imageNamed:str];
[Images setImage:img];
img = nil;
[self.view addSubview:Images];